# Redirection code is not working on webnode

Tags: html

I have added this code to my webnode html but it's not working. Can anyone have the solution.

```
<script>
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            window.location='https://google.com'
        }, 3000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted this and it seems to work. What are you running it on? and what browser. I used MS Edge on Windows 10 Pro to test it and just added the HTML tag

```
<html>

<script>
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = 'https://google.com'
    }, 3000);
</script>

</html>
```